# python ldap attribute query

Tags: python, ldap

I am trying to modify a python based-authenticator for murmur (voip software) to work with my ldap tree.

The LDAP authenticator is available at:

http://www.winex.org/linux/zealot/src/mumble-scripts/Authenticators/LDAP/LDAPauth.py

It works, but not quite with my ldap layout, so I have to modify it a bit. I know an approach that could work, but unfortunately I have no more knowledge about python than what I learned from google (I have some other programming expertise though).

My ldap layout looks like this:

```
charName=xxx, ou=people, dc=xxx, dc=com
```

Under this there are attributes stored such as `userPassword` and `login` among others.

The python script above is tailored to use a ldap bind to authenticate. In this case I would have to bind as `"charName=logindatafromapp, ou=people, dc=xxx, dc=com"`. Unfortunately people don't log in with `"charName"` but with `"login"` which is an attribute, but isn't identical with `"charName"`.

I do not know a way to bind to an attribute, so here is my idea:

- I first bind as ldap admin and perform a search over all entries for `"logindatafromapp"` and match that value against `"login"`. If a match is found I grab the matching `"charName"` and re-bind with that `charName` as originally intended.

I am currently stuck on querying the `"charName"` value and at assigning that value to a variable, so i could use it in a second ldap bind (google didn't really help me).

Here is my code:

```
ldap_conn = ldap.initialize(ldap_uri, 0)
ldap_conn.bind_s("cn=admin,dc=xxxxxxxx,dc=com","pass")
res = ldap_conn.search_s('ou=people,dc=xxxxxx,dc=com', ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL,'login=trony',['charName'])
print(res)
```

It then prints `"[('charName=Trony,ou=people,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=com', {'charName': ['Trony']})]"`.

(the `"login=trony"`) is a temporary filter that I would have to replace with the `applogin` var. My problem is now how can I assign `"Trony"` (in this case) to a variable? The output seems to be a special struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Trony' is in

```
res[0][1]['charName'][0]
```

You take the first element of the list — it's a tuple; then the first element of the tuple; it's a dictionary; then value of the dictionary for the key 'charName'; it's a list once again; and then the first element of the list.

Comment: thanks a lot :), "name = res[0][0]{'charName'}[0]" doesnt' work though, says syntax error.

Comment: more specifically:   File "./LDAPauth.py", line 205
    test = res[0][0]{'charName'}[0]
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: was res[0][1]['charName'][0] :)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two alternatives:

- Use the method you describe to search for the entry using the information you have, in this case the value of the `login` attribute as entered by the user and then using the DN that was found in a simple or SASL bind or
- Use SASL with identity mapping to map the authId (the value of the `login` attribute) in such a way that a SASL bind will succeed where only the value of the `login` attribute is known

The first method requires a search and then a bind, the second might require that user entries have reversible passwords (AES is a good encryption scheme for that purpose) depending on the SASL mechanism that is chosen. Using SASL with the DIGEST-MD5 mechanism would provide a way to map identities as described (all professional-quality LDAP servers support such a mapping mechanism) and would obviate the need to send a password in the clear over a network, but has the disadvantage of not being as secure as using simple bind where the password is stored as a salted SHA-2 digest. Although DIGEST-MD5 should not be used because it requires reversible passwords and thus is not as secure as using the strong SHA-2 (with salt) it is available for applications that require it.